Как сделать закругленну обводку текста?
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такую обводку у текста?


Вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199351/4928642. Но придётся немного пошаманить...

Ответ обновлён.

@Qwertiy, прикольно задать вопрос в удалённом ответе ;-) Ну, Ок. Можно профиль почитать или навести на аватарку мою :)

@UModeL, хм.. прочитал - принципиально не согласен)

Есть инстукция и пример на её основе.
Я сделал немного иначе и получилось то, что ниже. И удачи с подбором ненулевых коэффициентов. stdDeviation и последний набор values отвечают за размер тени, а последнее значение в первых трёх наборах values управляет цветом. При небольшой толщине тень получается хорошо, но чем шире, тем больше блюр или пикселизация границы. Возможно, можно применить несколько фильтров.


body {
  font-family: "Kablammo", system-ui;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings: "MORF" 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.with-outline {
  position: relative;
  padding: .25em;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: .25ch;
}

.with-outline::before, .with-outline::after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  position: relative;
}

.with-outline::before {
  position: absolute;
  filter: url('#medal-text-filter');
}

.svg-with-filter {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kablammo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<svg class="svg-with-filter" aria-hidden="true">
  <filter id="medal-text-filter">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="1" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur" values="0 0 0 0 0.25  0 0 0 0 0.125  0 0 0 0 0.5  0 0 0 32 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>

Начинаем
<div class="with-outline" aria-label="В моменте"></div>
и продолжаем



Чтобы сделать широкую чёткую обводку без пикселизации надо применить фильтр многократно. Цвет текста и цвета в промежуточных фильтрах при таких формулах ни на что не влияют. Подбирать цвет надо только в последнем фильтре.


body {
  font-family: "Kablammo", system-ui;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings: "MORF" 0;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.with-outline {
  position: relative;
  padding: .25em;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: .25ch;
}

.with-outline::before, .with-outline::after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  position: relative;
}

.with-outline::before {
  position: absolute;
  filter: url('#medal-text-filter');
}

.svg-with-filter {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kablammo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<svg class="svg-with-filter" aria-hidden="true">
  <filter id="medal-text-filter">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur1" stdDeviation="1" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur1" result="matrix1" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 5 0" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrix1" result="blur2" stdDeviation="1" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur2" result="matrix2" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 5 0" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrix2" result="blur3" stdDeviation="1" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur3" result="matrix3" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 5 0" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrix3" result="blur4" stdDeviation="1" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur4" result="matrix4" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 5 0" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrix4" result="blur5" stdDeviation="1" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur5" result="matrix5" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 5 0" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrix5" result="blur6" stdDeviation="1" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur6" result="matrix6" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 5 0" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrix6" result="blur7" stdDeviation="1" />
    <!-- В последнем фильтре надо настроить цвета -->
    <feColorMatrix in="blur7" values="0 0 0 0 0.5  0 0 0 0 0.125  0 0 0 0 0.75  0 0 0 5 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>

Начинаем
<div class="with-outline" aria-label="В моменте"></div>
и продолжаем



А ещё можно сделать за две пары фильтров, но кажется, качество края получается хуже:


body {
  font-family: "Kablammo", system-ui;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings: "MORF" 0;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.with-outline {
  position: relative;
  padding: .25em;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: .25ch;
}

.with-outline::before, .with-outline::after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  position: relative;
}

.with-outline::before {
  position: absolute;
  filter: url('#medal-text-filter');
}

.svg-with-filter {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kablammo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<svg class="svg-with-filter" aria-hidden="true">
  <filter id="medal-text-filter">
    <!-- В первых двух надо настроить жирность -->
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur1" stdDeviation="4" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur1" result="matrix1" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 64 0" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrix1" result="blur2" stdDeviation="1" />
    <!-- В последнем фильтре надо настроить цвета -->
    <feColorMatrix in="blur2" values="0 0 0 0 0.5  0 0 0 0 0.125  0 0 0 0 0.75  0 0 0 16 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>

Начинаем
<div class="with-outline" aria-label="В моменте"></div>
и продолжаем




Вот вариант на фильтрах идеальный, жаль не выйдет нормально изменять цвет обводки)

@De.Minov, цвет можно сделать любой - надо только 3 числа поменять. Проблема в том, что мои ожидания о том, как их менять, не оправдались, поэтому я их тупо подгонял руками, когда использовал эту обводку.

text-stroke такую обводку делает, но перед текстом. Поэтому поверх ещё раз написал(прошу прощение за позиционирование на костылях)). С круглым шрифтом обводка будет круглее.
Ещё как вариант - наложить эффект из svg.


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #222;
  color: darkred;
}

.outer {
  display:inline–block;
Font-size: 3em;
   font-style: italic;
}
.shadow {
-webkit-text-stroke: 15px #fff;display:inline–block; position:absolute;
}
.inner {
position:relative;
display:inline–block;
}
   Lorem ipsum <div class=outer><div class=shadow>в моменте</div><div class=inner>в моменте</div></div> foo barr




Углы не скруглённые, плюс ещё треугольники торчат. Когда я пытался так сделать, пришёл к выводу, что это тупиковый путь.

В svg есть параметр для скругления углов.

@Qwertiy в шрифте как у тс  углы вылетать не будут

спорно. Тем более, у М есть палка влево - она вылезет почти наверняка.

Вылет угла образуется от того что касательные идут под острым углом. Если шрифт сделан без острого угла - завернется норм даже на малом радиусе.

я запостил ответ с нормальными скруглениями, но его допиливать надо будет)

У меня получилось.



.x {
  font-size: 50px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .5em rgba(0, 150, 0, .5);
  /* без прозрачности текст накроет */
}

.y {
  font-size: 50px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .5em rgba(0, 150, 0, .3);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 0 0 lime);
  /* по идее тут можно поиграться с чем то вроде
  mix-blend-mode: difference
  выдергивая текст из его же обводки. в таком случае можно
  было бы избавиться от прозрачности, но чот не уверен */
}

.z {
  font-size: 50px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .5em lime;
  paint-order: stroke fill;
}
<i class='x'>ну например так...</i>
<br>
<i class='x'>в моменте</i>
<br>
<i class='y'>или так...</i>
<br>
<i class='z'>ну например так...</i>



UPD
наконец-то вспомнил как обводко-опускатель называется...
вдоль и поперёк font- & text- облазил а оно paint-order называется... :face-palm:
и - интуитивно
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order
в сниппете применил к классу .z

Углы не скруглённые, плюс ещё треугольники торчат. Когда я пытался так сделать, пришёл к выводу, что это тупиковый путь.

Обводка выше текста)

@eri, о чём я вполне ясно предупредил в /* CSS */

@Qwertiy, в FF 91 всё вполне норм, разве что точки весёлые(меджу точкой и обводкой пространства куча).

@puffleeck, а я в хроме)

@puffleeck, да, в FF намного лучше: https://i.sstatic.net/cWVJ0sAg.png

Ну углам в хроме не помогло, но за paint-order плюсик - не знал, что такой существует.

У меня получилось)

@Qwertiy, слухай, мб всё таки дополним один из этих -webkit-text-srokeов? спрашиваю потому что у меня такой вариант на win7(с DirectX 9/10 разумеется) выглядит почти идеально(никаких треугольников и наслоений, только круги вокруг точек). надо набросать таблицу +- такого вида: OS | версия DX/OpenGL/vulkan | browser | скриншот. ну и в заголовке обозначить что этот вариант сейчас в сатусе "как делать НЕ надо". сделал бы и сам, но ничего свежее 7ки под рукой нет и не предвидится. как выяснится(из таблицы) кто всё таки виноват(ОС, браузер иль таки граф. либа) постучать в соответствующий саппорт

@puffleeck, у меня win11, mac и android имеются.

@Qwertiy, и у меня 7ка. всяко лучше чем ничего. + под таблицей что-то вроде опросника устроить, чтоб остальные свои варианты докидывали. ну как на мете в теме с никами.
